# Using DATETIME in WHERE clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, where-clause

I have this query

```
SELECT  
    [MsgNumber], [StateAfter],
    DATETIMEFROMPARTS (SUBSTRING([TimeString], 7, 4), 
                       SUBSTRING([TimeString], 4, 2), 
                       SUBSTRING([TimeString], 1, 2),
                       SUBSTRING([TimeString], 12, 2), 
                       SUBSTRING([TimeString], 15, 2), 
                       SUBSTRING([TimeString], 18, 2), 0) AS dt
FROM 
    TABLE
WHERE 
    [MsgNumber] IN (5, 9, 13, 17)
ORDER BY 
    dt ASC, StateAfter ASC
```

OUTPUT (ok):

```
+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+
| MsgNumber | tateAfter |           dt            |
+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+
|         9 |         1 | 2018-03-09 17:22:00.000 |
|         9 |         0 | 2018-03-09 17:23:37.000 |
|        17 |         1 | 2018-03-09 17:23:37.000 |
|        17 |         1 | 2018-03-09 17:29:43.000 |
|        17 |         1 | 2018-03-09 17:36:21.000 |
+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+
```

I want to add a condition on date; to avoid error in internal datetime coding, i use the DATETIMEFROMPARTS function like that

```
SELECT [MsgNumber],[StateAfter]
,DATETIMEFROMPARTS ( SUBSTRING ( [TimeString] ,7 , 4 ), SUBSTRING ( [TimeString] ,4 , 2 ), SUBSTRING ( [TimeString] ,1 , 2 ),
                    SUBSTRING ( [TimeString] ,12 , 2 ), SUBSTRING ( [TimeString] ,15 , 2 ), SUBSTRING ( [TimeString] ,18 , 2 ) , 0) as dt
FROM TABLE
WHERE [MsgNumber] IN (5,9,13,17) AND (dt > DATETIMEFROMPARTS(2018,4,9,0,0,0,0) and dt <  DATETIMEFROMPARTS(2018,5,9,0,0,0,0))
ORDER BY dt ASC,StateAfter ASC
```

ERROR:-

> Messaggio 207, livello 16, stato 1, riga 5 
>   Invalid column name 'dt'. 
>   Messaggio 207, livello 16, stato 1, riga 5 
>   Invalid column name 'dt'.

Can someone help me to understand why it doesn't work? I tried also the BETWEEN clause; Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot refer to a column alias in the `where` clause.  The typical solutions are to use subqueries or CTEs.  But SQL Server has another method that I like, `apply`:

```
SELECT [MsgNumber], [StateAfter], v.dt
FROM TABLE t CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (DATETIMEFROMPARTS(SUBSTRING ([TimeString], 7, 4), SUBSTRING([TimeString], 4, 2), SUBSTRING([TimeString], 1, 2),
                    SUBSTRING([TimeString], 12, 2), SUBSTRING( [TimeString], 15, 2), SUBSTRING([TimeString], 18, 2), 0)
             )
     ) V(dt)
WHERE [MsgNumber] IN (5, 9, 13, 17) AND
      v.dt > DATETIMEFROMPARTS(2018, 4, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0) AND
      v.dt <  DATETIMEFROMPARTS(2018, 5, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0))
ORDER BY dt ASC,StateAfter ASC;
```

I find it curious that you don't use the simpler:

```
WHERE [MsgNumber] IN (5, 9, 13, 17) AND
      v.dt > '20180409'  AND
      v.dt < '20180509'
```

(I did not use hyphens because this format will always be interpreted as YYYYMMDD regardless of internationalization settings.)

Comment: I didn't used  v.dt > '20180409'  AND
      v.dt < '20180509' because I needed datetime in the condition; Can I use same logic writing "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS" ?

Comment: @AnielloLettieri . . . SQL Server will translate `'20180409'` to a datetime, if appropriate.   For a constant datetime, I would write it as YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.

Answer (score 0):

Alias `dt` can not be used inside `WHERE` clause. Use a subquery like:

```
 SELECT t.[MsgNumber]
    ,t.[StateAfter]
    ,t.dt
FROM (
    SELECT [MsgNumber]
        ,[StateAfter]
        ,DATETIMEFROMPARTS(SUBSTRING([TimeString], 7, 4), SUBSTRING([TimeString], 4, 2), SUBSTRING([TimeString], 1, 2), SUBSTRING([TimeString], 12, 2), SUBSTRING([TimeString], 15, 2), SUBSTRING([TimeString], 18, 2), 0) AS dt
    FROM TABLE
    ) t
WHERE [MsgNumber] IN (
        5
        ,9
        ,13
        ,17
        )
    AND (
        dt > DATETIMEFROMPARTS(2018, 4, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        AND dt < DATETIMEFROMPARTS(2018, 5, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        )
ORDER BY dt ASC
    ,StateAfter ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You Are getting this error Because in your Table there is no Such a Column dt. dt is Just an Alias Name that you have given in the select so its not a Column. So You Can use any of the below methods :

**Using CTE or SubQuery** (Recommended )

```
; with CTE
AS
(
    SELECT [MsgNumber],[StateAfter]
    ,DATETIMEFROMPARTS ( SUBSTRING ( [TimeString] ,7 , 4 ), SUBSTRING ( [TimeString] ,4 , 2 ), SUBSTRING ( [TimeString] ,1 , 2 ),

SUBSTRING ( [TimeString] ,12 , 2 ), 
SUBSTRING ( [TimeString] ,15 , 2 ), SUBSTRING ( [TimeString] ,18 , 2 ) , 0) as dt
        FROM TABLE
)
SELECT
    *
    FROM CTE
WHERE [MsgNumber] IN (5,9,13,17) 
    AND 
(
dt > DATETIMEFROMPARTS(2018,4,9,0,0,0,0) and dt <  DATETIMEFROMPARTS(2018,5,9,0,0,0,0))
    ORDER BY dt ASC,StateAfter ASC
```

**Giving the Formula in Where Condition** (Not Recommended )

```
SELECT [MsgNumber],[StateAfter]
,DATETIMEFROMPARTS ( SUBSTRING ( [TimeString] ,7 , 4 ), SUBSTRING ( [TimeString] ,4 , 2 ), SUBSTRING ( [TimeString] ,1 , 2 ),
                    SUBSTRING ( [TimeString] ,12 , 2 ), SUBSTRING ( [TimeString] ,15 , 2 ), SUBSTRING ( [TimeString] ,18 , 2 ) , 0) as dt
FROM [TABLE]
WHERE [MsgNumber] IN (5,9,13,17) AND 
(
    DATETIMEFROMPARTS ( SUBSTRING ( [TimeString] ,7 , 4 ), SUBSTRING ( [TimeString] ,4 , 2 ), SUBSTRING ( [TimeString] ,1 , 2 ),
                    SUBSTRING ( [TimeString] ,12 , 2 ), SUBSTRING ( [TimeString] ,15 , 2 ), SUBSTRING ( [TimeString] ,18 , 2 ) , 0)
                > DATETIMEFROMPARTS(2018,4,9,0,0,0,0) 
    and 
    DATETIMEFROMPARTS ( SUBSTRING ( [TimeString] ,7 , 4 ), SUBSTRING ( [TimeString] ,4 , 2 ), SUBSTRING ( [TimeString] ,1 , 2 ),
                    SUBSTRING ( [TimeString] ,12 , 2 ), SUBSTRING ( [TimeString] ,15 , 2 ), SUBSTRING ( [TimeString] ,18 , 2 ) , 0)
                <  DATETIMEFROMPARTS(2018,5,9,0,0,0,0))
ORDER BY dt ASC,StateAfter ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

This error happned because dt is not a physical column.

You can achieve like below query:

```
    SELECT tbl.* FROM ( SELECT  
        [MsgNumber], [StateAfter],
        DATETIMEFROMPARTS (SUBSTRING([TimeString], 7, 4), 
                           SUBSTRING([TimeString], 4, 2), 
                           SUBSTRING([TimeString], 1, 2),
                           SUBSTRING([TimeString], 12, 2), 
                           SUBSTRING([TimeString], 15, 2), 
                           SUBSTRING([TimeString], 18, 2), 0) AS dt
    FROM 
        TABLE ) tbl
    WHERE tbl.[MsgNumber] IN (5,9,13,17) 
AND (tbl.dt > DATETIMEFROMPARTS(2018,4,9,0,0,0,0) AND tbl.dt <  DATETIMEFROMPARTS(2018,5,9,0,0,0,0)) 
    ORDER BY 
        tbl.dt ASC, tbl.StateAfter ASC
```